# Adding 3 onclicks to one page

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add 3 onclick popups to one page. But it seems as soon as I add the second one the first one stops working. I renamed them different and still wont work. Please help.

```js
<script>
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>

<script>
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("mypopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>
```

```html
<span class="tooltip" onclick="myFunction()">
<div class="amount">$234.41</div>
<span class="tooltiptext" id="myPopup">This is how much money our community has raised to help provide meals and support to animal charities in our local communities.</span>
</span>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Fur Baby Of The Month -->
<span class="tooltips" onclick="myFunction()">
<div class="furbm">
<img src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/icons/amazon.png">
</br>
</div>
<span class="tooltipstext" id="mypopup">Fur Baby Of The Month
</br>
<img src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/search-icons/duck.png">
</br>
congratulations "Fluffy"
</span>
</span>
```

Comment: how does the code know which "myFunction" to call? actually there will only be one "myFunction" ... but imagine if there were two ... how would the code "know"?

Comment: I thought changing this line  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");

Comment: @mikesmith the thing is about the *signature*, both have the same name (`myFunction`). Which is the entry point. Therefore, your html doesn't know the difference about them, everything inside the functions is unknown to the outside.

Comment: changing a line inside a function doesn't prevent it from overloading an existing function ...besides, again .. if it were possible to have two functions of the same name, how can you determine which one to call (you can't)

Comment: simple solution ... create unique function names for unique functions

Comment: So do I change that name in the other 2? Thanks

Comment: Would someone know how i can add click on the page and it closes the pop up. Thanks

Comment: Two different functions should not have the same name within a given scope. Two HTML elements should not have the same ID. Two HTML elements can, however, belong to the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Your span content were not valid HTML - you cannot wrap a div in a span - and `</br>` is the wrong way around - should be `<br/>` if you want the XHTML slash

Here is the recommended way

1. target the container (delegate/delegation)
2. use the class of the clickable element
3. use a data- attribute to name the element you want to access when clicking
   Alternatively use erlative addressing by wrapping each item in a yet another container div and use `tgt.closest(".parentClass").querySelector(".popupClass")` to access the popup

Here I use the data-attributes - as you can see it does not matter if the popup is a span or a div in this case.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // on page load
  document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) { // clicking anything in the container
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains("tooltip")) { // we clicked a tooltip
      const show = tgt.dataset.pop; // getting the data-pop content
      document.getElementById(show).classList.toggle("hide");
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span class="tooltip" data-pop="myPopup1">Look</span>
  <div class="amount">$234.41</div>
  <span class="tooltiptext hide" id="myPopup1">This is how much money our community has raised to help provide meals and support to animal charities in our local communities.</span>
  <hr/>
  <span class="tooltip" data-pop="myPopup2">Look</span>
  <div class="furbm">
    <img src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/icons/amazon.png">
  </div>
  <div class="tooltipstext hide" id="myPopup2">Fur Baby Of The Month
    <img src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/search-icons/duck.png"> congratulations "Fluffy"
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to close when clicking elsewhere, you can again use addEventListener and test that the target is not the popup and not the popup link and then close all open popups. That code is a little more complex